# SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all variable length parameters to have an explicitly set non-zero Size

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, parameterized-query

I tried to insert some values in SQL database by the code:

```
var connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString; ;
var conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Trainer] (Name, ID, [Trainee Counter], image, [Mobile NO], Email, Password) VALUES(:v1, :v2,:v3,:v4,:v5,:v6,:v7);", conn);

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("v1", SqlDbType.VarChar));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("v2", SqlDbType.Int));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("v3", SqlDbType.Int));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("v4", SqlDbType.VarBinary));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("v5", SqlDbType.VarChar));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("v6", SqlDbType.VarChar));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("v7", SqlDbType.VarChar));
command.Prepare();
command.Parameters[0].Value = TextBox1.Text;
command.Parameters[1].Value = 0;
command.Parameters[2].Value = 0;
command.Parameters[3].Value = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
command.Parameters[4].Value = TextBox3.Text;
command.Parameters[5].Value = TextBox4.Text;
command.Parameters[6].Value = TextBox5.Text;


command.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

But I always get this exception:

> SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all variable length parameters to
>   have an explicitly set non-zero Size.

Actually I have ported this code from one of my C++/CLI project with PostgreSQL, and it works fine on that project.

Comment: Not sure if it may be the issue, but you are setting `v2` as `Int` but assigning a `String` value.

Comment: @SJuan76 I have edited my code, but the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can should add your parameter like this instead:

```
command.Parameters.Add(@"v1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
command.Parameters.Add(@"v2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
command.Parameters.Add(@"v3", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
command.Parameters.Add(@"v4", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
command.Parameters.Add(@"v5", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text;
command.Parameters.Add(@"v6", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text;
command.Parameters.Add(@"v7", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox5.Text;


command.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

But personnaly I prefer to add my parameter like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"v1",  TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"v2", 0);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"v3", 0);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"v4", FileUpload1.FileBytes);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"v5", TextBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"v6", TextBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"v7", TextBox5.Text);
```

Comment: Doesn't using `.AddWithValue()` leave it up to ADO to determine the datatype?  Is that the best approach in this case?

Comment: yes, I prefer it because if you have the wrong parameter type you will be screwed when you execute your command, second approach saves you from trouble

Comment: @meda What is wrong in my way? Why it works with C++/CLI but not in C#?

Comment: @meda So what mistake I did?

Comment: @Aan to be honest I cant give you a real answer few things can go wrong when you do things like that manually(type mismatch in your app or database field), also you should `prepare()` only after you set your command and parameter, in your post you do it before you set your parameter

Answer (score 8):

you should set max size of variable length parameters

replace all varchar (and varbinary) parameters:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("v1", SqlDbType.VarChar));
```

with:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("v1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `parameter.Size` to the database's maximum size of the column corrected the problem for me when I ran into this.

```
For Each parameter As SqlClient.SqlParameter In command.Parameters
   parameter.Value = row.Item(parameter.SourceColumn)
   parameter.Size = Me.mData.Columns.Item(parameter.SourceColumn).MaxLength
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand.Prepare() requires all variable parameters tobe non zero .
```

please check wether any value is empty.

Check for Null or Empty:

```
command.Parameters[0].Value = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text.ToString()))?TextBox1.Text.ToString():"Empty";
command.Parameters[1].Value = 0;
command.Parameters[2].Value = 0;
command.Parameters[3].Value = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
command.Parameters[4].Value =  (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox3.Text.ToString()))?TextBox3.Text.ToString():"Empty";
command.Parameters[5].Value = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox4.Text.ToString()))?TextBox4.Text.ToString():"Empty";
command.Parameters[6].Value =  (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox5.Text.ToString()))?TextBox5.Text.ToString():"Empty";
```

Comment: Same issue. no benefit.